# How to get a RichEmbed from the channel by field value?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I'm creating the bot for my Discord channel. I created a special system based on requests. For example, the user sends a request to be added to the chat he wants. Each request is paired with a unique ID. The request is formed and sent to the service channel where the moderator can see those requests. Then, once the request is solved, moderator types something like `.resolveRequest <ID>` and this request is copied and posted to *'resolved requests'* channel.
There is some code I wrote.
Generating request:

```
if (command === "join-chat") {
        const data = fs.readFileSync('./requestID.txt');

        let requestID = parseInt(data, 10);

        const emb = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle('New request')
            .setDescription('Request to add to chat')
            .addField('Who?', `**User ${msg.author.tag}**`)
            .addField('Which chat?', `**Chat: ${args[0]}**`)
            .setFooter('Request\'s ID: ' + requestID)
            .setColor('#fffb3a');

        let chan = client.channels.get('567959560900313108');
        chan.send(emb);

        requestID++;

        fs.writeFileSync('./requestID.txt', requestID.toString(10));
    }
```

Now the `.resolveRequest <ID>`:

```
if (command === '.resolveRequest') {
        msg.channel.fetchMessages({limit : 100}) //getting last 100 messages
            .then((messages) => messages.forEach(element => { //for each message get an embed
                element.embeds.forEach(element => {
                    msg.channel.send(element.fields.find('value', args[0].toString(10))); //send a message containing the ID mentioned in 'args[0]' that was taken form the message
                })
            }));
    }
```

`.join-chat <chat_name>` works flawlessly, but `.resolveRequest <ID>` does't work at all, even no errors. 
Any way to fix it?

Comment: You might want to take a look at how to use [.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Also, this is something best handled with a database of some sort to store the message id associated with the request id. As opposed to searching through all message for a given request id. You shouldn't be using Discord messages as you data storage/retrieval.

Comment: @Anu6is actually discord.js, has a now deprecated( use a function instead ) , `.find('value', 'key')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.find('value', 'key')` is deprecated, use `.find(thing => thing.value == 'key')` instead.

Also you should use a DataBase to store things, but your Code actually is not broken, its just that you check for: `command === '.resolveRequest'`, wich means you need to run `..resolveRequest`, as in the `command` variable the prefix gets cut away so change that to: `command === 'resolveRequest'`